# Gradle NoClassDefFoundError when running jar

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, velocity, noclassdeffounderror

I'm trying to set up a Gradle project with some Velocity functions in it.

So far I have the following files:
**src/main/java/com/veltes/velotest.java:**

```
package com.veltes;

import org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine;
import org.apache.velocity.Template;
import org.apache.velocity.VelocityContext;
import org.apache.velocity.exception.MethodInvocationException;
import org.apache.velocity.exception.ParseErrorException;
import org.apache.velocity.exception.ResourceNotFoundException;
import org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeConstants;
import org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader;

import java.io.*;

public class velotest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            VelocityEngine ve = new VelocityEngine();
            ve.setProperty(RuntimeConstants.RESOURCE_LOADER, "classpath");
            ve.setProperty("classpath.resource.loader.class", ClasspathResourceLoader.class.getName());
            ve.init();
            VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext();
            context.put("name", "World");
            Template t = ve.getTemplate("com/veltes/velotest.vm");
            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
            t.merge(context, writer);
            System.out.println(writer.toString());

            File logFile = new File("C:/users/xxxx/Desktop/velotest.html");

            try {
                writeFile(logFile, t, context);
            }
            catch (IOException io) {
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

    }

    private static void writeFile(File logFile, Template t, VelocityContext context) throws IOException {
        Writer logWriter;

        logWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(logFile));
        try {
            t.merge(context, logWriter);
        }
        catch (ResourceNotFoundException rnfe) {
        }
        catch (ParseErrorException pee) {
        }
        catch (MethodInvocationException mie) {
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
        }
        logWriter.flush();
        logWriter.close();
    }

}
```

**build.gradle:**

```
group 'velocitytest'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.5

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.3.11'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'

    compile 'velocity:velocity:1.4'
}
```

Now, when I run `gradle assemble` and `gradle build` everything is fine, but when I try to run the project (same for running the built jar in build/libs/ and for running the velotest class in IntelliJ), I get the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections/ExtendedProperties
>       at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.< init >(RuntimeInstance.java:183)
>       at org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine.(VelocityEngine.java:60)
>       at com.veltes.velotest.main(velotest.java:23)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.collections.ExtendedProperties
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>       ... 8 more

It's a bit strange that there is no jar in build/tmp/
Does anyone of you knows a solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a runnable jar if you want to be able to run it.

You can use shadojar plugin or extend the jar task to pack the runtime deps into an artifact.

```
jar {
    archiveName = 'Name.jar'

    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'your.main.class',
                'Class-Path': configurations.runtime.files.collect { "lib/$it.name" }.join(' '),
                'Implementation-Version': project.version
    }

    from(configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }) {}
}
```

For intelliJ problem:

```
apply plugin: 'idea'
```

Then run `gradle idea` task, this will refresh .iws .ipr .iml files in your project and sync the classpaths. Or if you use intelliJ support (which is not yet ideal) try to refresh it there. I think in version 2017.1.3 the gradle integration is a bit better.

Comment: Thank you. This works for the jar.
Do you also have a solution for running the class in IntelliJ? There I still get the same error.

Comment: probably is not in sync, try to apply plugin: 'idea' and then run gradle idea, this will refresh the .ipr .iws. .iml files and classpaths.

Comment: Updated to IntelliJ 2017.1.3. Now it works. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Adding
`from(configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }) {}` to `build.gradle` file fixed it for me, like this:

```
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes(
            'Main-Class': 'gradle22.Library'
        )
    }
    from {
        configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
}
```